# VW Transporter T5 - p1503 Generator Terminal DF (Load signal) Signal Improbable

Tags: vw, alternator, wiring, generator

I have a VW Transporter T5 2007 with 2.5 TDi BNZ engine. I have the following fault code (among many):

**p1503 Generator Terminal DF (Load signal) Signal Improbable**.

This fault code gets repeated logged after about 5 minutes of driving at the same time as the ASR light comes on.

On SEATS (Also VAG group), apparently this is often a broken wire in the alternator loom, but I cannot find any information for VW T5s for this fault.

Please can any one advise what might cause this.

Comment: How many wires are on the alternator plug? How many volts is the alternator outputting?

Comment: It may be a two wire plug with L and DF terminals in which case DF is the terminal you want to look at. It should have ignition voltage (14+v) on it. If it doesn't unless you know where on the ignition circuit it connects to you're going to have to cut the wire loom open and visually inspect everything.

Comment: Thank you. I will have a look and report back. It wont be until next weekend now though.

Comment: @Dib what was the outcome of this? Did you manage to solve the fault or find out what it was?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I ran out if money repairing the damn thing and had to sell it at a huge loss.